# Why are the new releases of Geany editor having problems with some characters?

Tags: text-editor, geany

I have installed Geany recently and I observed that the characters like: . , < etc. are not being entered in the editor unless I press them twice - after I press them for the second time, they appear two times in the editor. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could be something specific to your system, as Geany works fine here on Fedora Linux 31 \w Xfce. What operating system and, if applicable, desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows10 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the keybaord layout to English(Canada) and it should do the job for you.

Reference: https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1902